# TTL for AtomicLong in Apache Ignite

Tags: nginx, lua, ignite, rate-limiting

Is it possible to add TTL for AtomicLong in Apache Ignite or for any atomic objects?

Just for my pet project I created Rate Limiting service in Lua Nginx + Apache Ignite and store RL keys in AtomicLong. But I need TTL or any possible eviction configuration for my AtomicLong counter.

Comment: How many rate-limiting keys do you have?

Comment: Key for every second, if rate-limiting per second.
Key for every minute, if rate-limiting per minute etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do, but I don't think AtomicLong is the way to go. I would suggest a cache with a TTL defined for whatever time window you want. Rather than increment your AtomicLong, you insert a new record for every hit. Your count is just the size of the cache.

Comment: I have to increment and get a counter atomically due to concurrency.